# Problem in recursion programme to print numbers

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have problem in below programme, below programme print number from 1 to 9, but i want to print number 10 also, how can i do that?

```html
function a(n){
    if(n == 1){
        return;
    }
    a(--n);
    console.log("hello world = ",n);    
}

a(10);
```

Comment: swap `console.log` and `a` calls. Or don't mutate `a` (`a(n - 1)`).

Comment: I have swapped a and console.log but it prints 10 to 2 now.

Comment: Before return on 1 console it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch the exit condition and call the function only if you have a number which is not zero.

```js
function a(n) {
    if (n !== 1) a(n - 1);
    console.log("hello world =", n);
}

a(10);
```

What you have is

```
function a(n){
    if (n == 1) {                     // exit condition
        return;                       // end of function run
    }
    a(--n);                           // mutating variable
    console.log("hello world = ", n);
}
```

an exit condition which checks the value and ends the function. This prevents to print the last value.

Another problem is the cange of `n` by calling the function again. The later used variable dos not have the original value anymore.

By changing the exit function to a check if the function should be called again, as the opposite of exit, it allows to run for each wanted number and make an output.

If you just change the `--n` to `n - 1`, you need another output for `1`.

```js
function a(n){
    if (n == 1) {
        console.log("hello world = ", n); // add another output here for 1
        return;
    }
    a(n - 1);
    console.log("hello world = ", n);
}

a(10);
```

Comment: Thanks, But how can i do it for 1 to 10.

Comment: Can you please guide me what is the difference between my above programme and your given programme.

Comment: But Why its start from 2 and print till 10 if i use n-1 instead of --n;

Comment: But why the output is different, with n-1 and --n, as we can see both these are same.

Comment: it is not the same. by using `n - 1`, `n` keeps the old value.